# No route matches [POST] "/projects/16/todos/35/edit"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post

I am Receiving this error

> No route matches [POST] "/projects/16/todos/35/edit"

I understand that I don't have to put a method for that, but how can I add it

This is **routes.rd**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  get 'projects/index'
  post 'projects/new'

  resources :projects do
    resources :todos
end
  root 'projects#index'
end
```

This is **edit.html.erb** (for a task)

```
<h1>Edit Task</h1>

<%= form_for :todo, local: true do |form| %>
  <p>

    <%= form.label :body %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :body %>
  </p>

  <div>
<%= form.submit%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is **todos_controller.rb**

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  end

  def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @todo = @project.todos.create(todos_params)
    redirect_to projects_path
  end

  def edit
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @todo = @project.todos.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @todo = @project.todos.find(params[:id])
    @todo.save
  end

def destroy
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @todo = @project.todos.find(params[:id])
  @todo.destroy
  redirect_to projects_path
end

  private
    def todos_params
      params.require(:todo).permit(:body)
    end
end
```

Please help to fix this problem

Comment: `/edit` is a GET action - it displays editing form. You probably messed it up with `/update` which is PUT.

Comment: Replace `:todo` in the edit view with `@todo`. Rails doesn't understand what you are trying to do when you provide a symbol. If you don't provide an url, than it's going to post to the current url you're on. However by providing an object it can check if it's a _new_record?_ or not and it can check what the object type is to figure out the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from here, the request fired is **POST** request, instead it should be a **GET** request

> Receiving this error No route matches [POST]
>   "/projects/16/todos/35/edit"

Make sure to fire **GET request** when you click on **Edit TODO**.

Defined routes with

```
resources :projects do
    resources :todos
end
```

are

```
 project_todos GET    /projects/:project_id/todos(.:format)          todos#index
                  POST   /projects/:project_id/todos(.:format)          todos#create
 new_project_todo GET    /projects/:project_id/todos/new(.:format)      todos#new
edit_project_todo GET    /projects/:project_id/todos/:id/edit(.:format) todos#edit
     project_todo GET    /projects/:project_id/todos/:id(.:format)      todos#show
                  PUT    /projects/:project_id/todos/:id(.:format)      todos#update
                  DELETE /projects/:project_id/todos/:id(.:format)      todos#destroy
```

So you can make use of rails view helper **edit_project_todo(project, todo)** in **link_to** for **Edit TODO** to fire GET request.

Answer (score 0):

in your edit.html.erb

```
<h1>Edit Task</h1>

<%= form_for @todo, :url => project_todo_path(@project,@todo), :html => { class: "your_class", :method => "put" } do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :body %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :body %>
  </p>

  <div>
    <%= form.submit%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Note: - `form_for` is used for any object and and here your object is `@todo` not `todo` and by default `form_for` hits `create` action if `@todo` is of new and if `@todo` is existing record then it will hit update action, here explicitly you can provide `url` to which action is will hit after submitting form . so here i have manually provided action of update and also provided `method: :put` because by default `form` is of `POST` type request.
hopefully it will clear you doubts.